# Unable to load native Hadoop library

Tags: hadoop, x86

I already saw these kind of problems but it didn't solve anything for me.

So I've got Kubuntu 15.04

```
uname -a  
Linux laptop 3.19.0-31-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 15:03:41 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux  

echo $HADOOP_OPTS  
-Djava.library.path=/opt/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1/lib/native

sbin/start-dfs.sh   
15/11/19 14:35:51 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on [OpenJDK Server VM warning: You have loaded library /opt/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.]

java -version  
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

So since I've got a 32 bit system. I shouldn't have those problems at all?
And more over since I already tried the HADOOP_OPTS with native and without native at the end, that doesn't seem to change anything as well.
What could it be then?

Comment: IIRC, 32bit Linux can still use non-executable memory pages to give NX protection, when running on hardware that supports this.  Why would you even use 32bit Linux, though?  yuck.

Comment: It's an older netbook - 2 x Intel Atom, N450 @ 1,66GHz .. it seems to be 64 bit and I've got no idea why I've got a 32bit OS ... should still work though, right?

Comment: Yes, according to Intel: http://ark.intel.com/products/42503/Intel-Atom-Processor-N450-512K-Cache-1_66-GHz says N450 supports Intel64 (and of course the execute-disable bit for page tables, so you *can* still have problems in 32bit mode, which was my point).  I don't use Hadoop, so IDK about installing it.  But yes, I'm sure it works on 32bit Linux.  Just pointing out that you picked the worse option by installing 32bit Kubuntu, and that 32bit doesn't mean you can ignore warnings about execstack and stuff.